# React Native - How to initialize object in class component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I got this error message when I'm trying to initialize an object in the class component.

Error message

```
    Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /blockchain/node_modules/react-native/App.js: Unexpected token (9:6)
```

My code

App.js

```
import Block from './block.js'

export default class App extends Component {

  let genesisBlock = new Block(); //error here
  let blockchain = new Blockchain(genesisBlock);

  render() {
    return (
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

block.js

```
export default class Block {
    constructor() {
        this.index = 0
        this.previousHash = ""
        this.hash = ""
        this.nonce = 0
        this.transactions = []
     }

     addTransaction(transaction) {
        this.transactions.push(transaction)
    }

    get key() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.transactions) + this.index + this.previousHash + this.nonce
    }
}
```

But if I remove `let`, it said `variable genesisBlock not found`.

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/blockchain-reactnative

Comment: ```genesisBlock = new Block();``` ... no let needed (or var)

Comment: already done but still same. any sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import Block from './block.js'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.genesisBlock = new Block();
    this.blockchain = new Blockchain(this.genesisBlock);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got variable genesisBlock not found.

Comment: sorry, try `this.genesisBlock` in `this.blockchain`, not `genesisBlock`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your render has a closing View tag with no opening one.